# Viewport3D Content does not fit into its boundaries when size changed or maximized

Tags: .net, wpf, 3d

I am developing a MainWindow which contains Viewport3D the problem is when the window first open everything is ok, but when I change the size of Viewport3D some 3D objects are clipped
I think I need to know the equation which calculate number of units in x, y, z axes so I can rebuild the scene taking into consideration their length